# How to properly use the System.Random class?

Tags: vb.net, random

Whenever I try to use the `Random.Next` method, it will choose 1 random variable and return that every time. I'm trying to generate two random integers to use for coordinates in this class, so that I can make multiple `Enemy` objects, each with their own coordinates.

```
Public Class Enemy
    Dim _name As String
    Public Property name() As String ...

    Dim _start_point() As Integer
    Public Property start_point() As Integer()
        Get
            Return _start_point
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer())
            _start_point = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Dim _length As Integer
    Public Property length As Integer ... 

    Dim _space_filled(,) As Integer
    Public Property space_filled As Integer(,) ...


    Dim gen_x As New Random()
    Dim gen_y As New Random()


    Public Sub New(ByVal namep As String, ByVal lengthp As Integer)
        name = namep
        length = lengthp

        ReDim _start_point(2)

        GenerateStartPoint()
        Debug.Print(name & " start point: {" & start_point(0) & ", " & start_point(1) & "}")
    End Sub

    Public Sub GenerateStartPoint()
        start_point = {gen_x.Next(0, 10), gen_y.Next(0, 10)}
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Make it *Shared*.  You only need one.

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain to me why that worked? Edit: Nevermind, I think I get it.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a single instance of new Random() and then call Random().Next() whenever you need a separate variable.  Since Random() derives it's seed from the CPU time, if you instantiate 2 nearly simultaneously they will be produced from the same seed.

Comment: So doesn't that mean that if I make two new instances of Random to create my coordinates, they'll be the same number since they were instantiated at the same time?

Comment: Precisely, so you just need the 1, and just called .Next(), and it will produce a new number each time.  When the Random is created, it creates a collection of random values to be used based on it's Seed value.  The seed value is based on part of the CPU time, so when they are created at the same time, they have the same seed so they have the same collection of numbers.